# DokuWiki Downloader

Tags: web-crawler, documentation, dokuwiki

I am using this framework, which has Documentation in DokuWiki. The developers of this framework warned that the documentation will disappear, thus forcing users to switch to the new version of the framework.

It is imposible to me to switch to new framework, because it would require code refactoring of... everything in my every app. Therefore I need to download their documentation and I want to have it in DokuWiki syntax.

I have an account with privilege to edit pages, therefore I can see the DokuWiki syntax of every page.

***QUESTION***: Is there a way to crawl through all the pages of DokuWiki and get all of the articles in DokuWiki syntax (having of course such privilege)?

---

PS: Authors refused to deliver all of DokuWiki (licence is not the reason) and I don't want to use any site downloaders. I just want nice and clean DokuWiki syntax without having to crawl manually through all the pages, edit them and save the source.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they don't have the ?do=export_raw mechanism disabled, you can use it to fetch the raw wiki syntax of a single page (See http://www.dokuwiki.org/export).

A list of all pages can be obtained using the RSS feed (see http://www.dokuwiki.org/syndication) or Google Sitemap (see http://www.dokuwiki.org/sitemap).

Combining both in a small script should relatively simple.